# How to track time between incoming messages from socket server?

Tags: javascript, time, websocket

I have created a websocket (wss) client to listen to messages from a socket server. Messages are sent continuously from the server which is logged in console client side. I would like to measure the time between these messages (I know they happen once every 5 seconds but I need to calculate the time because the 5 seconds is not guaranteed).

I've thought about storing the previous message's time via Date.now() and then finding the time of the most recent messages to calculate the time difference but I'm unsure about how to do that.

```js
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data.substr(4, 9) === 'heartbeat') {
        console.log(event.data.substr(2))  // logs msg to console
        timeHeartbeats(event.data.substr(2), Date.now())
    }
}

// I'm not actually keeping track of the time for 2 messages which is the issue
const timeHeartbeats = (json, mostRecent) => {
    console.log(Date.now() - mostRecent)   // 0 b/c Date.now() is the same as mostRecent (should be ~5000ms if time calc is correct)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time since last Heartbeat:

```js
    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      if (event.data.substr(4, 9) === 'heartbeat') {
        console.log(event.data.substr(2))  // logs msg to console
        timeFromNow(event.data.substr(2))
      }
    }

    // I'm not actually keeping track of the time for 2 messages which is the issue
    const timeHeartbeats = (mostRecent) => (json) => {
      const now = Date.now();
      console.log((now - mostRecent) + ' since last heartbeat');
      mostRecent = now;
    }

    const timeFromNow = timeHeartbeats(Date.now());
```

Comment: thanks it worked! i didn't change the onmessage call to the newer version of timeFromNow which is why i thought nothing was working. Really appreciate it!